# Adb install apk failure

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

my problem is about android and the adb commands. I'm working on a Nexus 5 and i want to install and apk with adb commands. So i start with adb devices, my mobile is detected by the computer so i go to the repertory where the apk is located and i launch `adb install name.apk`

It returns :
`* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5038 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
- waiting for device -`

The Nexus 5 is rooted, and usb debug is activated

`adb devices` give me some sort of serial number of the mobile

Comment: What does it say when you do adb devices?

Comment: @alex It prints out access denied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `adb devices` gives you a list of devices, then you could try to take serial number of your device and call `adb -s <serialNumber> install name.apk`. Here is [more options](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) you could try.

Comment: Thanks it worked !But do you have any explanation for my problem ? It worked well last week, i could install apks this way, and not anymore

Comment: This must be a temporal issue. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408674/adb-error-device-not-found

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ubuntu try restarting the adb server by giving sudo permission.cd > adb location and do sudo ./adb kill-server and sudo ./adb start-server.